# How to change a variable value depending on the system being used? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

E.g. if Windows is used, add this option:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default)
```

in case of OS X:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default')
```

I could not find any information on this topic. It's kind of more a question about how usually in development os versions problems are resolved? E.g for GitHub: should I write and push 2 versions of code for each OS?